# Nginx serving "location /" but not serving "location /project-name/" specified in /etc/nginx/sites-available/ config file

Tags: nginx, flask

I'm very new to Nginx and am using it to configure my website in the following way:

1. Request for http://xx.xx.xx.xx/ -> Nginx should serve static html files from the /var/www/html directory
2. Request for http://xx.xx.xx.xx/project-name/ -> Nginx should call Python Flask application through WSGI (using UNIX socket)

Here is my /etc/nginx/sites-available/project-name file:

```
server {
   listen 80:
   server_name xx.xx.xx.xx;

   root /var/www/html;

   location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
   }

   location /project-name/ {
      include wsgi_params;
      uwsgi_pass unix:/home/user-name/project-name/project-name.sock
   }
}
```

When I type http://xx.xx.xx.xx in the browser, I'm served the default Nginx page. But if I type http://xx.xx.xx.xx/project-name/ in the browser, I get a 404 (Requested URL not found) error.

Now the thing is, if I point "location /" to the Flask application as below, then the Flask application works fine and returns the proper page (but http://xx.xx.xx.xx calls the Flask application, and I'm unable to serve static html files directly from Nginx):

```
server {
   listen 80:
   server_name xx.xx.xx.xx;

   location / {
      include wsgi_params;
      uwsgi_pass unix:/home/user-name/project-name/project-name.sock
   }
}
```

Am I missing something simple?

Answer (score 0):

It was a simple oversight.

In my Flask App, I was handling route '/' instead of '/project-name/'.